# Is it appropriate to say « ça rigole pas » as an angry word?

Tags: expressions

Frustrated with parking violations, I said jokingly:

> Franchement, qu’est ce qu’ils n’ont pas compris dans « défense de stationner » ?! Je n’en peux vraiment plus, de ces conducteurs qui font fi de toutes les règles ! Si j'étais à même de coller des contraventions, **ça rigolerait pas**, moi je te le dis !

What I meant by this phrasing was that I would take a really tough stance and crack down hard on parking violations – so much so that there would be hell to pay for such violators!

I usually associate this expression with a positive context where you find yourself impressed by something, so I'm not sure if you can use it as a harsh word, albeit jokingly.

Comment: I think what strikes me most here is not seeing “ça rigole pas” used angrily, but rather seeing it used in the conditional. I realize that you're stating a present/future “Contrary-to-fact condition” (which usually would require the conditional w/a “si” clause in the imperfect, just as you did), but maybe if you expressed the possibility w/more certainty (with your “si” clause [or a less formal one] in the present), you could use the “futur proche” (which, to me, seems a bit more natural for this angry usage): “Si [jamais] chuis élu comme Tsar des PVs, **ça va pas rigoler,** moi je te le dis!”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Ça rigolerait pas*** properly translates what you want to express. Parking enforcement would be taken seriously so violators would feel the pain.

That said, while a native French could have been the author of these sentences, note that different levels of languages are mixed in them:

> *Franchement, qu'est ce qu'ils n'ont pas compris…* : standard spoken French
>
> *qui font fi de toutes les règles* : formal/literary
>
> *Si j'étais à même…* : formal/literary too
>
> *coller des contraventions* : casual
>
> *ça rigolerait pas, moi je te le dis !* : colloquial

Comment: Merci. Yes, mixed register, that is what I need to keep working on! The way you have laid out their varying registers, I almost feel like a master of mixed register, haha...

Comment: @Alone-zee To help you, here's a version in an informal register: « Putain, qu’est c'qu’y-z-ont pas compris dans « défense de stationner » ?! J’en peux vraiment plus, d'ces conducteurs qui se foutent de toutes les règles ! Si c'était moi qui collait les contraventions, ça rigolerait pas, moi j'te l'dis ! »

Comment: @Gilles Merci. It's not always easy to keep the register consistent in spontaneous speech like this, as I usually use the first expression that  instinctively springs to mind.

Comment: And here is a moderately still informal version: *Franchement, qu’est ce qu’ils n’ont pas compris dans « défense de stationner » ?! J’en peux vraiment plus d'ces conducteurs qui s'fichent d'toutes les règles ! Si j'avais le droit de coller des contraventions, ça rigolerait pas, moi j'te l'dis !*